# unable to install Visual Basic ()

Tags: dll, windows-8, vb6, registry, regsvr32

I am trying to install Visual Basic 6 Enterprise Edition on Windows 8 Server (64-bit) , but I got the errors, saying "Setup could not remove the file: C:\Windows\system32\DBNMPNTW.DLL".  So, I used "LockHunter" to lock the file and continue, but it does not proceed ([see attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX5Pk.jpg)).  So, I chose "ignore" button to proceed(assumed that the file is the only problem). However, I got the following two files that give me the error, saying "Setup could not remove the file"

(1). C:\Windows\system32\DBNMPNTW.DLL
(2). C:\Program Files(x86)\Common Files\system\oledb\SQLOLEDB.DLL

[Setup could not remove the file http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/96146-javasigndll-error/](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/96146-javasigndll-error/)
So, I clicked "ignored" for both errors, and then I got different error type, saying "..was unable to register itself in the system registry."([see attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my52M.jpg)). See below for the lists of the file names.

[image: unable to register itself in system registry] 
So, I copy fresh dll files from online, and try to register all dll files(found on [this site](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/96146-javasigndll-error/)), and I got the error below ([see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl8YO.jpg)).

[image: regsvr32]
Thanks in advance,

Comment: `I copy fresh dll files from online` those are very often not legit, the wrong version or infected

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, I figured my mistake, and luckily, I kept all of my original files. So, I revert all of them.  Thanks for reminding me :)